# Office.js throws exception when tried to read cell address if Excel is kept Open for 20-30 min and then try to read cells value

Tags: office-js

I am using office.js i am trying to read the cell value by passing the address of cell to a function. it works all fine but sometime it just throws exception and exception messages are too general that you do not know what the issue is.

look at the function below its all good but some time i get error when ctx is tried to sync at return     ctx.sync().then(function () {

```
public getDataAtRange(rangeAddress: string): JQueryPromise<any[]> {
            let defer = $.Deferred();

            if (rangeAddress !== null) {
                Excel.run(function (ctx: Excel.RequestContext) {
                    let range = rangeAddress.split("!");
                    let sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(range[0]);
                    let selectedRange = sheet.getRange(rangeAddress);
                    selectedRange.load(["values", "text"]);

                    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                        let data: any[] = [];
                        for (let i = 0; i < selectedRange.text.length; i++) {
                            for (let j = 0; j < selectedRange.text[i].length; j++) {
                                let text = (selectedRange.text[i][j]).trim();
                                let value = selectedRange.values[i][j];
                                if (text !== "") {
                                    let cellValue: any = { value: "", text: "" };
                                    cellValue.value = value;
                                    cellValue.text = text;
                                    data.push(cellValue);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        defer.resolve(data);
                    });
                }).catch(function (error: any) {
                    console.log("Error in getDataAtRange(): " + error);
                    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                    }
                    defer.reject("Error in reading cell value, make sure the selected cell is not in Edit mode.");
                });
            } else { defer.resolve(); }

            return defer.promise();
        }
```

**Most of the time this error can be consistently reproduce if excel is kept open for 20-30 min and then tried to read its cell value.**

this is the error message i get.
Error in getDataAtRange(): GeneralException: An internal error has occurred.
Debug info: {}

**error message from code**

[image]

Comment: Could you paste in the full error text and code -- and also the JSON.stringify-ed error.debugInfo?

Comment: there is not much details in the error message. i will need some time to get it. error message was something like internal server error

Comment: Got it.  I'm curious if debugInfo will reveal anything...

Comment: i will be waiting for updates from your end, do let me know if you have something

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, what I meant is:  could you please provide the details of the debugInfo, and maybe even the stack trace. Once we have that, it will be much easier to narrow down our investigation.

Comment: Hi Michael,please find the log message "Error in getDataAtRange(): GeneralException: An internal error has occurred.
Debug info: {}
"

Comment: Ok, I will admit that the error isn't particularly enlightening...  let me see if I can repro myself, and go from there...

Comment: hi Michael, are you able to reproduce the issue. its coming on my machine right now if you want to take a look..also i have attached the error screenshot..i am not going to close the session on my machine, if you want to take a look do let me know

Comment: I just tried to repro it with an Excel session where I ran your code, waited 2 hours, ran it again multiple times... and it works like a charm.

Comment: Oh, wait, I see!  This is Excel Online we're talking about, not Desktop, correct?

Comment: correct, issue is reproducible on my machine. right now..let me know if you need any more info...also its not always reproducible.

Comment: I think that what is happening is that the Office Online session times out.  Have you tried entering in a cell value within the sheet when this happens?  I'm pretty sure the whole page reloads.  Could you confirm?

Comment: my file was in readonly mode(default mode when you click any file in one drive), which i can not edit manually, unless i click on edit button on excel toolbar. but my app can write on it. and data is displayed to user. I have created new file in edit mode and now i am waiting for it to show the error i will update you if i get the error.

Comment: That would be great, thanks!  My guess is that after X many minutes, the document loses connection with the server.  On a writeable document, I think you can see it in the way that the whole view refreshes when you try to enter something in.  But I suppose you're correct that it's harder to see what is going on with a read-only view

Comment: but this issue also shows when excel file is in edit mode. I was not able to reproduce but my other project mate could reproduce it.

Comment: hi Michael, i could reproduce this issue on my machine, even when excel is in edit mode. But when i click on excel cell, it ask me to refresh the page and after that i dont see the issue. any design suggestion you would like to give to me to fix this issue for my customer

Comment: Hi Shyam, I've confirmed that this is indeed a bug that we need to investigate -- we should at minimum be providing you with a specific error code and message, saying that the session has timed out.  I don't have details yet on the amount of work that is involved to fix this, or the timing -- but we'll keep this thread posted when we do.