# When Excel online window is idle for a while all calls to Excel will fail

Tags: office-js

For example, I let the Excel online with my addin opened and I go to make a late, when I get back to my desk, and wants to do some operation in the addin that will do things like open an new worksheet. The call will fail

[image: Error when calling Excel.js]

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug (or at least, something where we should surface a better error).  It was previously mentioned in [Office.js throws exception when tried to read cell address if Excel is kept Open for 20-30 min and then try to read cells value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210749/office-js-throws-exception-when-tried-to-read-cell-address-if-excel-is-kept-open).  I will follow up with the team.